# Roaming Profiles - How it works?

Tags: roaming-profiles

So a roaming profile = needs to be a domain user account who can login to other workstations? If so, does it means all domain users = roaming profiles?

So when a roaming user logs in to another computer, what are the things that are the same? Desktop shortcuts are same, desktop background. How about files? If i have some files in the desktop, will it still be there? It follows the same file structure as in local which is c:users/ ?

How about if i have some bookmarks in my chrome, will the same bookmarks be there?

And also application, if in my primary computer i have a program, will that program be in new machine?

Thanks

Comment: My experience is that nothing is the same between computers. If I log in to another PC on our corporate network I get only the software that PC has, and if I open Outlook I'll need to wait 12 hours for it to sync 5 gig of emails - so I use the web email client or my phone instead. The best option I've found when moving around is to use the new PC with Remote Desktop to get access to the old PC I left behind, so that I can use my software.

Answer (score 2):

> So a roaming profile = needs to be a domain user account who can login to other workstations?

Yes.

> If so, does it means all domain users = roaming profiles?

No, the converse is not necessarily true. Roaming profiles are an opt-in feature.

(In fact, Microsoft wants to deprecate this feature in favor of folder redirection, which accesses files directly over the network instead of copying the massive directory on every login.)

> So when a roaming user logs in to another computer, what are the things that are the same? Desktop shortcuts are same, desktop background. How about files? If i have some files in the desktop, will it still be there? It follows the same file structure as in local which is c:users/ ?

If I remember correctly, most of the "profile directory" (`C:\Users\foo`) is migrated, minus specific "local-only" folders. So your registry is copied; `Desktop` and `Documents` and other folders are copied; `AppData\Roaming` is copied; but `AppData\Local` is not.

The file structure is exactly the same otherwise – Windows just copies the whole thing.

> How about if i have some bookmarks in my chrome, will the same bookmarks be there?

Depends on whether Chrome saves them in `AppData\Local` or `AppData\Roaming`...

> And also application, if in my primary computer i have a program, will that program be in new machine?

No. Programs are not usually part of your profile; they're installed system-wide. (There can be exceptions though, but they're usually in AppData\Local and therefore won't roam anyway.)

Comment: So if a domain user who is not a roaming profile logs in to another computer? There wont be any files in there for him ?

Comment: Right, they'll get a completely fresh profile (unless they use Folder Redirection).